# Get link to file I uploaded to DNN Website

Tags: web, dotnetnuke

**How do I get a link to a file I have uploaded to my website?**

I have uploaded a file to my website by going to *Admin - File Manager* then I uploaded the file to this destination *Portal Root\Pages\Customisation* how do I then get a link to the file I just uploaded?

The file is *myFile.PDF* so I have tried this path but it doesn't send me back the file:

```
 http://mywebsite.com.au/Pages/Customisation/myFile.pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "portal root" is typically housed in the directory "Portals/0," so the full URL would be `http://mywebsite.com.au/Portals/0/Pages/Customisation/myFile.pdf`.  If you have multiple sites/portals within the DNN installation, that you'll need to find the ID, instead of assuming that it's 0.

There's also a small possibility that the home directory has been customized to some other directory name entirely.  But you can verify the directory on the *Advanced Settings* tab of *Site Settings*, in the *Page Management* section.